# Python socket & threading issues

Tags: python, sockets, python-multithreading

I'm having trouble with my start_server() and accept_connections() functions. I want to start a non-blocking infinite loop to accept connections.
Basically, accept_connections() should run the infinite nonblocking loop to accept connections from socket and spin off new threads for every connection. I tried testing it, but I get some sort of infinite loop and I don't think that I'm doing this right.

```
import threading
import socket
import random

class HighCardServer:
    def __init__(self, address, port, backlog):
        #set parameters as self's attributes
    
    def start_server(self):
        s = socket.socket()
        s.bind((self.address, self.port))
        s.listen(self.backlog)
        HighCardServer.accept_connections(s)
        s.close()

    def accept_connections(server):
        while True:
            c, addr = server.accept()
            print("Connected to", addr)
            t = threading.Thread(target=HighCardServer.client_connect, args=(server))
            t.start()
        
    def client_connect(self, c):
        #function that intects with client
```

Comment: I'm asked to include a non-blocking loop to be able to handle multiple connections at once. I edited my code since I'd forgotten to include the while loop

Comment: Note that the loop in `accept_connection()` does block inside the `accept()` call, and that is most likely the behavior you want.

Comment: I guess I'm tryint to run a test file for this module and when I run pytest I get stuck in some infinite loop. The loop was there with or without the inclusion of the while loop in accept_connections(). The test file basically creates 2 HighCardServer objects and runs a few games on each. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you are defining your thread, you need to give it a target instead on calling it:

```
def accept_connections(server):
        c, addr = server.accept()
        print("Connected to", addr)
        t = threading.Thread(HighCardServer.client_connect(), args=(server)) # Calling function
        t.start()
        server.close()
```

Try giving the thread a target by:

```
def accept_connections(server):
        c, addr = server.accept()
        print("Connected to", addr)
        t = threading.Thread(target=HighCardServer.client_connect, args=(server))
        t.start()
        server.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't catch that. I appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions with the loop? I'm not sure that I'm doing it right

Comment: I haven't ever worked with socket so im not really sure. Sorry I cant comment on that.

Answer (score 0):

I see several problems in the code as posted:

1. You're passing the `server` socket to the `client_connect` function rather than `c`, so `client_connect` can't actually talk to the socket that communicates with the client.
2. The value passed to the `args` argument must be a tuple, which means it must include a comma -- simply putting parentheses around the socket isn't sufficient to convert a string into a one-item tuple.  So the correct argument is `args=(c,)`, not `args=(server)`.

See working code as shown below (I tested it by running `python3 test.py` in one Terminal, and then running `telnet 127.0.0.1 5555` in a second Terminal):

```
import threading
import socket
import random

class HighCardServer:
    def __init__(self, address, port, backlog):
        self.address = address
        self.port = port
        self.backlog = backlog

    def start_server(self):
        s = socket.socket()
        s.bind((self.address, self.port))
        s.listen(self.backlog)
        self.accept_connections(s)
        s.close()

    def accept_connections(self, server):
        while True:
            c, addr = server.accept()
            print("Connected to", addr)
            t = threading.Thread(target=self.client_connect, args=(c,))
            t.start()

    def client_connect(self, c):
        print("Client connected via socket ", c)
        c.send("Hello sailor\n".encode())
        c.close()

h = HighCardServer('', 5555, 5)
h.start_server()
```

Running the server shows this:

```
$ python3 test.py
Connected to ('127.0.0.1', 59253)
Client connected via socket  <socket.socket fd=5, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 5555), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 59253)>
Connected to ('127.0.0.1', 59255)
Client connected via socket  <socket.socket fd=5, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('127.0.0.1', 5555), raddr=('127.0.0.1', 59255)>
```

And running the telnet client shows this:

```
$ telnet 127.0.0.1 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello sailor
Connection closed by foreign host.

$ telnet 127.0.0.1 5555
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Hello sailor
Connection closed by foreign host.
```